# Any diff/merge tool that provides a report (metrics) of conflicts?

Tags: visual-studio, merge, diff, beyondcompare

**CONTEXT:** I am preparing a big C# merge using visual studio 2008 and TFS. I need to create a report with the files and the number of collisions (total changes and conflicts) for each file (and in total of course)

**PROBLEM:** I cannot do it for two reasons (first one is solved):

**1-** Using TFS merge I can have access to the file comparison but I cannot export the list of conflicting files... I can only try to resolve the conflicts.
**(I have solved problem 1 using beyond compare. It allows me to export the file list)**

**2-** ***Using TFS merge I can only access manually for each file to get the number of conflicts***... but I have more than 800 files (and probably will have to repeat it in the close future so is not an option doing it manually)

There are dozens of file comparison tools (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools ) but I am not sure which one could (if any) give me these metrics. I have also read several forums and questions here but are more general questions (which diff tool is better) and I am looking for a very specific report.

**So my questions are:**

1. Is Visual Studio 2010 (using
   still TFS2008) capable of doing such
   reports/exportation?
2. Is there any
       tool that provide this kind of
       metrics (Now I am trying Beyond Compare)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to my question after several days investigating:

*1- Visual Studio 2008 & TFS 2008 cannot export any information.*

*2- After trying several tools: 
**BeyondCompare 3** allows getting metrics from IU and easily export them. (Used File Compare Report/XML Dump filtering files instead of using Folder Compare Report.)
**KDiff3** allow getting some metrics using IU, but is not possible to export them.*

Did not tried command line approach

NOTE: be aware that different tools have different conflict resolutions so metrics will be not 100% accurate. For example a file with 20 changes and 3 conflicts in TFS was reported as 20 changes 8 conflicts using beyond compare.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to merge a huge number of files, you want to minimize the differences reported to the barest minimum.   Line-oriented diff tools report changes if the code is reformatted, or there's any change in a line.

The [SD C# Smart Differencer](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SmartDifferencer) reports differences based on source code syntax, not the physical layout of the text.  It reports changes based on language elements (identifiers, expressions, statements, blocks, methods, ...) in terms of effect (insert, delete, copy, move, rename) from the point of view of the programmer.  (The rename detection means it will ignore names changed consistently across a block/file).

Reporting this way tends to produce considerably smaller diffs than line-oriented diffs, thus using less of your attention.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Smart Differencer could be interesting. But What I need is metrics on the future merge to seize it. It's not important at this stage if the merge is smart or line by line.

Comment: Hmm.  Well, most diff tools (including SmartDifferencer) produce an output telling you where diffs are, and you could just count the number of differences each tool reported.  You'd need something like AWK or PERL to do that counting since the output is not always "neat" but it shouldn't be difficult in any sense.   If you are going to count reported diffs, then *how* the diff is done will give you considerably different counts and thus different sizing.

Comment: I tried some diff tools. BEYONDCOMPARE does give me the number of diffs when comparing one file with other but don't give it to me when comparing folder to folder. (Or I was not able to get this info). KDIFF3 does give me the list but is nearly no possible to export it (Tomorrow I am going to print the report as pdf, copy&paste to an excel sheet and sum it up)

Maybe I need to investigate and call these tools from command line...

I was hoping any tool that had the option of comparing two folders and an easy generate a report of the conflicts found.

Comment: "Computed results" and GUIs pretty much don't happen together.  The command line approach (recurse across directories, run you diff tool, collect data-per-file, sum-up) is probably your best bet, and really shouldn't be much work.